# Xpath is changing from system to system

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests

Regarding automation testing, One system Xpath is different on another system. Because of this cannot able to run it on multi-system.Is that xpath is changing from system to system.?..

Comment: Can you elaborate? the Xpath you're mentioning is not related to XML's XPath, right?

Comment: @Raptor. To perform selenium automation testing, There are many ways to locate element like id, css selector, xpath etc.. Iam using xpath (taken by firebug Addons). But some of the elements are unable to locate on some others Pc with same version. Is that xpath is changing from system to system.?..

Comment: xpath should be the last resort for locating elements, because it breaks easiely. normally it should'nt be different from system to system. can you show us the code of the element and your location method? Which error do you get?

Comment: For us there is no Id available to locate element. So that used xpath. Is there any other options in such sort of situation.?. we are following Open2Test framwork and getting "Unable to find element with xpath".